# why am I getting an npm deployment error on digital ocean?

Tags: json, npm, deployment

I'm very new to deployment and am coming across errors that I simply can not find an answer for on google. I'm using digital ocean and the log is below.

```
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.
```

this seems self-explanatory. It seems I have to install something at npm version 5 or later. Is that correct? If so I'm not sure why I'm getting this as I have the latest version of npm installed. It does mention my package.json file so I will paste that below here. If I you need to see anything else please let me know. I have no idea where to even start with this and I'm trying to get the project uploaded for work.

```
{
  "name": "prime-solo-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.0",
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mui-datatables": "^3.7.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.16",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.13.7",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-iframe": "^1.8.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "sendmail": "^1.6.1",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "client": "react-scripts start",
    "server": "nodemon --watch server server/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "heroku-run-build-script": true
}
```

Comment: Is your lockfile under version control?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, but I did see it was in my gitignore. I took it out of there, recommitted, and it seems to be working. I feel silly. It's still building as we speak so I'll reply back if it still doesn't work, but it seems to be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! My packagelock.json was in my gitignore and so digital ocean didn't pick it up because it wasn't there. I guess that'll do it lol!